# PrestaShop - insert products script

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I am looking for sql or php script which shows how to insert integrated data represents product with its attributes, images etc. to PrestaShop database. Does anyone know steps of this process - I mean name of tables and columns I need to fill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the source!! You have access to every classes, so just take a look at `Product.php` and `ObjectModel.php` and you will have every infos you need about the fields and the tables.

If your goal is to insert products, you don't need to write any sql queries. I would recommend to use the methods provided to avoid any errors.

Comment: How is it possible i cant find the ps_products table in my presatshop database? The other tables are there like: ps_category, ps_category_product.Is this an error?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not recommend use the ObjectModel (Prestashop Classes), **this is too slow** for big imports (+10000 products with categories and features), **SQL inserts is the fastest method**, but this is not easy task, you need fill a lot of tables:

- ps_product
- ps_product_lang
- ps_product_shop
- ps_stock_available
- ps_category_product
- ps_image
- ps_product_download

Luck!

Comment: This list assumes a basic product import without warehousing, features, carriers or other potentially necessary information. I would hate to manually fill all of the ancillary tables necessary for a more complicated site, when you can build a model product within the backoffice and duplicate said product record from within the back office. True, if you are adding 10,000+ records that isn't going to work, but if you are doing that, a module utilizing existing object classes would be a better approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is HIGHLY INADVISABLE! Mostly because of the complexity of the table relationships. Not saying it is impossible, but the sql statements I believe will have to be multi-part for each record. I have a live store with more than 12,000 active products and somewhere around 8,000 inactive products in the database and this is NOT something I would attempt to do (though I have attempted it multiple times on test sites with only marginal success).

I would suggest MANUALLY creating the required number of (semi-configured) blank product records within the target category and then doing an import using those record id's contained within the product_id column in the import file to add the desired products by updating the "blank" records previously created. The product data for import can be manipulated with excel and exported as a csv file, facilitating the addition of those products using the existing object model and classes within prestashop written for this purpose.

Just my .02 worth