# Importing databases in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a big database in Access with products I want to insert in Prestashop!
I've read about the database import in prestashop but didnt find anything about access db import. Is there a way to import this database in prestashop?
Or am I supposed to write sql queries to add these products. I have read the source code of prestashop like `Products.php` or `ObjectModel.php`like said here:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068141/prestashop-insert-products-script`. So is the only way to write sql queries?
Thanks!

Comment: The native import in Prestashop is, in all probability, the most complex thing or, depending on the interpretation, not very well done. I advise you to refer to some external module that has a high number of positive feedbacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PrestaShop have tools to import products from CSV, you can check it in BO > Advanced Parameters > CSV Import. You can choose what you want to import, products, categories, attributes etc. If your file is too big you supposed to split it to few small files.

Comment: Thanks a lot  ! I ll try

Comment: Good and nice idea !

Comment: The only other reliable option is to write a script using the Prestashop object model to create new objects and save them to the database. If you need to do this import regularly (e.g. the data is from another system that does ordering/stock control) then it may be worth the effort. You can use the CSV admin import code as an example of how to perform the steps in the process. I've done this successfully to import/update data from a custom xml stock file.

Answer (score 1):

As Agnes said CSV will be the option.

Since I still don't have enough rep I can comment on his response but I'd like to add that in the CSV import page you can find templates for the CSV may be useful if you are not used to Prestashop Product Fields.

Also if you upload the images to a temporal folder and add the URLS in the product CSV the images will be imported and added to the product.

If is the first product upload I'll also recommend you to set up the IDs for the products this way if something doesn't fit or you want to change the uploaded products you can do it just by ID or simply delete all previous products and import the new ones.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Import is very complecated in PrestaShop, and not really fonctionnal.

I recommand to use the module Migration pro. Is a paid module, but it works really fine, i've used it a lot.

Otherwise, you can read this article (in french), you have the list of table to import. After that, you can import images and regenerate them.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Modern Prestashop can directly import xls/xlsx files
It is much better choice than CSV because you don`n have mess with field delimiters.
Export from Access to Excel should not be problem.
Native Import through web admin GIU is very good.
But you need some practice:

1. Make file with few products - you can delete them later if you not satisfied with results of import.
2. Look carefuly at field mappings. Maybe you will fail at first attempt or miss some mapping - thats why you need to import few products first.

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to use the built in webservice api or you can make your own custom import module

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).